no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer fastlane
Fastlane File
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play internal track"
  lane :internal do
    # Fetching the current version code from Google Play
    google_play_info = google_play_track_version_codes(
      
      track: "internal"
    )

    # Debug output to inspect google_play_info
    UI.message("Google Play Info: #{google_play_info}")

    #if google_play_info[:version_codes].nil? || google_play_info[:version_codes].empty?
    #  UI.user_error!("Could not fetch version codes from Google Play")
    #end

    current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max.to_i

    new_version_code = current_version_code + 1

    # Define a helper method to increment version code in build.gradle
    def increment_version_code_in_gradle(new_version_code)
      gradle_file_path = "./app/build.gradle"
      gradle_content = File.read(gradle_file_path)
      updated_content = gradle_content.gsub(/versionCode\s+\d+/) do |match|
        "versionCode #{new_version_code}"
      end
      File.write(gradle_file_path, updated_content)
    end

    # Increment the version code in build.gradle
    increment_version_code_in_gradle(new_version_code)

    # Build the AAB (Android App Bundle)
    gradle(
      task: "bundle",
      build_type: "Release"
    )

    # Upload the AAB to the internal track on Google Play
    upload_to_play_store(
      track: "internal",
      aab: "./app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab",
      
    )
  end
end

Error is
Error in your Fastfile at line 20
   18:      #end
   19:  
=> 20:      current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max.to_i
   21:  
   22:      new_version_code = current_version_code + 1
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

auto increment in version number google play store using Faslane

The error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer fastlane", means that ruby tries to convert a Symbol to an Integer, meaning that you passed a Symbol to somewhere that expects an integer.
Let's see the offending line.
current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max.to_i

There is only one symbol here. From this my initial suspicion was that google_play_info is not a hash (that would be indexed by symbols), but is an array instead (that would need to be indexed by integers).
google_play_info = google_play_track_version_codes(
  track: "internal"
)

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/google_play_track_version_codes/

Returns: Array of integers representing the version codes for the given Google Play track

The docs indeed say that this is an Array.
I don't know exactly what you intended to do, but a possible fix is to just remove the hash access since you're already dealing with version codes. Also, since it returns an array of integers, then the .to_i is redundant as well.
current_version_code = google_play_info.max


current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max

thank you, dear. I am not with Ruby (Fastlane). I want to get the version number from the Google Play Store and auto-increment it in the pipeline using Fastlane. so I have researched and share the sample code of Fastlane File.
after replacing
From
current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max.to_i
To
current_version_code = google_play_info[:version_codes].max
The error is the same
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

remove [:version_codes]: just current_version_code = google_play_info.max 
